# Jquery syntax in a view of MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a menu from actionLinks. All of the links have some id. According to the list which I transfer to the view, I want some of the links to be visible, and some not. Here is my whole view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>My Page</h2>
@foreach (var item in (List<MyTemplate>[])ViewData["myList"])
{
    if (item == "something1")
    {
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#someId').hide();
         });
         </script>
    }
    if (item == "something4")
    {
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#someOtherId').hide();
         });
         </script>
    }
}
```

Is this good?

**EDIT: the links source code**

```
<div id="menucontainer"> 
    <ul id="menu"> 
        <li id="id1">@Html.ActionLink("My home page", "home", "home")</li>
        <li id="users">@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li id="articles">@Html.ActionLink("Articles", "Index", "Home")</li> 
        <li id="id2">@Html.ActionLink("Photos", "Index", "Home")</li> 
        <li id="id3">@Html.ActionLink("about me", "Index", "Home")</li> 
        <li id="id4">@Html.ActionLink("sdsdf", "Index", "Home")</li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need javascript for that. If you build your links using server side you can set an `css class` to that link that indicates if the element is visible or not.

Comment: But the links aren't static. For example, now I want link1 to be invisible, and now I want link2. Can you provide an example pls?

Comment: Could you provide the source with your links please ?

Comment: <div id="menucontainer">
          <ul id="menu">
                    <li id="id1">@Html.ActionLink("My home page", "home", "home")</li>
                    <li id="users">@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li id="articles">@Html.ActionLink("Articles", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li id="id2">@Html.ActionLink("Photos", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li id="id3">@Html.ActionLink("about me", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li id="id4">@Html.ActionLink("sdsdf", "Index", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

Comment: I cant provide you a sample, not enough information. But you have to think about accessing your information that indicates `visible` or `not` and put that in the source you posted.

Comment: I agree wit @dknaack. You could put the logic in the creation of the links and add a cssclass that represents the state. Of course, I don't think it should be something like "hidden", but maybe it represents something from the functional perspective. Also, you can just remove the from the template if you won't use them (I mean, if there's no js for make them visible again)

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    @foreach (var item in (List<MyTemplate>[])ViewData["myList"])
    {
        if (item == "something1")
        {
            $('#someId').hide();
        }
        else if (item == "something4")
        {
            $('#someOtherId').hide();
        }
    }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Dynamically building JS isn't a good way of doing things, it doesn't let you pull the JS out to another file and makes it impossible to minify or use a CDN.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems this code is not something page independent. I just provided a better way to write the kind of solution that was asked. There are another methods and they are being covered in other answers.

Comment: could you provide the result html?